# keras LSTM model for timeseries not working

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, forecasting, quandl

I am using the below code to forecast timeseries data. I used Quandl data for it. But the same code works for a dataset bot wont work for another one. There are no compilation errors. But after model building step, i am not getting any results.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'my-quandl-code'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()

col = "Net"
df = quandl.get("ISM/MAN_PROD")  #Not working for this dataset

#col = "High" 
#df = quandl.get("EOD/HD") Works for this datset

df = df[col]
df = df.reset_index()
df =df.rename(columns = {"Date":"ds",col:"y"})

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
values = df['y'].values.reshape(-1,1)
values = values.astype('float32')
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)

train_size = int(len(scaled) * 0.9)
test_size = len(scaled) - train_size
train, test = scaled[0:train_size,:], scaled[train_size:len(scaled),:]
print(len(train), len(test))

def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset) - look_back):
        a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    print(len(dataY))
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

import numpy as np
look_back = 5
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=300, batch_size=100, validation_data=(testX, testY), verbose=0, shuffle=False)
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

please help.

Comment: Why did you disable shuffling for the fit call?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=300, batch_size=100, validation_data=(testX, testY), verbose=0, shuffle=False)
```

to:

```
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10, batch_size=100, validation_data=(testX, testY), verbose=1, shuffle=False)
```

In other words, train with fewer number of epochs first, and set `verbose=1` so that your program prints to `stdout` the progress of your training. If this runs successfully, then you can change the above line back to the original with higher number of epochs and 0 verbosity.

Comment: I did not suggest to reduce the number of epochs for training. Just to check if the code runs properly. @MathiasMüller

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to some null values in the dataset. I removed it and its working.Thanks.